# Android app installed has smaller size than apk package file?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I'm having a problem with an android apk installation. My apk is a cocos2dx game, has 11.5MB in size, I copied it to the SD card of an Android phone run 2.3.6 and 4.0 then installed it, but although "Application installed" message appeared I couldn't get it to Open/Run.

When I check the app in App Manager, the app had only 2.45MB in size.

Did anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am having half this problem, so I will try to contribute to the question (rather than having a real answer, sorry). While hoping for someone to be able to completely help us.

In my case, a "classic" Android game (no cocos2dx) but using Swarm and a Library project of my own. I use a Nexus One. My apk is 26 Mo and my app is only 1.57 Mo (after installing using adb install). If I deploy directly from Eclipse (without making the APK myself) my app is about 4Mo. I use preferExternal. **BUT** I can launch my game, and everything seems OK. Except of course the fact that it requires 25 Mo to install an app of 1.57 Mo...

Perhaps this is unrelated to your issue, but this proves that your problem is perhaps not related to the small app size compared to the APK file (one may think "ok so you have missing files, this is why it does not work")?

My first guess was that perhaps only the necessary things were installed (for example drawable-hdpi was not installed if your phone is mdpi) but this should change almost nothing in my case (I only have some small PNG and text files that are concerned).

This is particularly intriguing as I have a 16Mo MP3 file in my app.

Answer (score -1):

I can only answer for the size not why it can't open... probably the size of your installed apk some of it size is installed in sd card and some in internal memory because you install the apk file in sd card.